# CSS - Grid/Masonry Layout

Tags: css, css-float

I have created a grid layout like so ([**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ukEfY/1/)):

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-box">
    <div class="item-9">
        <div class="box-1"></div>
        <div class="box-2"></div>
        <div class="box-3"></div>
        <div class="box-4"></div>
        <div class="box-5"></div>
        <div class="box-6"></div>
        <div class="box-7"></div>
        <div class="box-8"></div>
        <div class="box-9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #990066;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    width: 49%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3333FF;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 400px;
    width: 26%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-3 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #993366;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-4 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF66FF;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-5 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CC66CC;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 140px;
    width: 24.5%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-6 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #9966CC;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 140px;
    width: 24.5%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-7 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CC6699;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-8 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #9966CC;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-9 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #990066;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    width: 49%;
}
```

And then I ran into a slight issue, I need box-2 left aligned to block-1 so basically i need to switch the positions of the big blue block with the 4 multicolored blocks. I have placed '>' and '<' arrows to illustrate what i mean.

Also I cant edit the HTML, as it is generated by PHP.. I can only edit the CSS. Also I cant Edit the sizes, such as width an Height.

Any Help Greatly Appreciated.

Comment: i mean... if the sizes and positions are fixed, you could always absolutely position all the boxes

Comment: the size of those boxes are static? (I see that you have fixed pixels)

Comment: well they are static in  height but thw widths are % in a 960 container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push the elements left and right with

```
position: relative
left/right: XX%
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/ukEfY/6/

```
/* ... */
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-2 {
    /* ... */
    position: relative;
    left: -25%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-3 {
    /* ... */
    position: relative;
    left: 26%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-4 {
    /* ... */
    position: relative;
    left: 26%;
}

/* ... */

.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-7 {
    /* ... */    position: relative;
    left: 26%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-8 {
    /* ... */
    position: relative;
    left: 26%;
}
/* ... */
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, your 1% off though on box-2, it should be left:-25%

Answer (score 0):

using absolute positioning, it can be done like that [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ukEfY/2/)

Notice: it's a very strict layout. (every position is fixed)

As you requested, the changes are only in the CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grid-box">
    <div class="item-9">
        <div class="box-1">1</div>
        <div class="box-2">2</div>
        <div class="box-3">3</div>
        <div class="box-4">4</div>
        <div class="box-5">5</div>
        <div class="box-6">6</div>
        <div class="box-7">7</div>
        <div class="box-8">8</div>
        <div class="box-9">9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.grid-box > .item-9
{
    position: relative;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > [class *= 'box-']
{
    position: absolute;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-1 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #990066;
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3333FF;
    height: 400px;
    width: 25%;
    left: 50%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-3 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #993366;
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
    right: 0;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-4 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF66FF;
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
    right: 0;
    top: 100px;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-5 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CC66CC;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 140px;
    width: 25%;
    top: 200px;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-6 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #9966CC;
    height: 140px;
    width: 25%;
    top: 200px;
    left: 25%;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-7 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #CC6699;
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
    top: 200px;
    right: 0;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-8 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #9966CC;
    height: 100px;
    width: 25%;
    top: 300px;
    right: 0;
}
.grid-box > .item-9 > .box-9 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #990066;
    top: 340px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you your answer looks Great, But.. I cant alter the widths of the divs.. Is there any other way?

Comment: without changing the DOM? I don't think so.. (but maybe someone else will succeed). if you want to change the dimensions of the boxes, you will have to recalculate the offset of the boxes.. it's not very good.. but it's the only way I can see right now.

Comment: What are the constraints as to why you cannot alter the divs?